# FireRequestAction not firing on button click

Tags: winforms, hosted, unified-service-desk

I have created a windows form hosted control. And I want to change focus on button click of Hosted Control to another application inside Unified Service Desk.

On Button Click event I am using below code,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs("CRM Global Manager", 
                       "ShowTab", "test application"));    
 }
```

but for some reason it is not getting fired. If i perform any other operation inside this code block like for example displaying a messageBox it works fine. But unable to fire this action.

Answer (score 0):

Never FireRequestAction.  Instead, always FireEvent, and then define Event and Action Call records in the USD configuration (rather than in the Hosted Control code, as you have been attempting).

In this instance, call FireEvent and provide the event with a meaningful name.  Next, write no further code.  Proceed to the configuration.  On your Hosted Control record, create a new Event record with an identical name.  If applicable, relate it to your Configuration record.  On this Event, add an Action Call to have the Global Manager do a ShowTab on your test application, and if applicable, relate this to your Configuration record as well.

Comment: Any particular reason why to FireEvent insteard of FireRequestAction?

Comment: Yes, there are a great many reasons.  You want a loose coupling, not a tight coupling here, and there are lots of reasons why.